# Debugging a NetBeans module with a NetBeans Maven Project

Tags: debugging, maven, netbeans

I have a NetBeans Module project using Maven loaded up in the NetBeans IDE.  I need to debug the module.  When I push the debug button I get the following error message:

> The IDE needs to define ${netbeans.run.params.ide} in order to run this action.  Currently you project's plugin configuration does not interpret this variable.  Adjust D:\mypath\pom.xml to use it defined?

In my pom I do not have the additionalArguments tag set and I have:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <netbeans.run.params.ide></netbeans.run.params.ide>
    <netbeans.run.params>${netbeans.run.params.ide}</netbeans.run.params>
</properties>
```

Even the pom navigator inside the IDE show that the property is there.  So my question is straightforward.  What the heck is causing that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the interrogation of somebody much smarter than me I have found the answer to this.  Somewhere along the line, something had added the line

```
<netbeans.run.params></netbeans.run.params>
```

to my ~home/.m2/settings.xml file.  This was overriding the property when the IDE tried to set it.